# Efficient Non-Regex extraction of hash tags from string?

Tags: php, performance, hashtag

Okay, I'm done with Twitter and I'm going to build my own. I could just `explode` all the whitespace and iterate and look at the first character of each string to find hash tags or does someone have an even more efficient method of finding hash tags that *obviously does not include the use of regular expressions*?

> ## Dwarf #jokes are only funny if you keep em #short.

Comment: You should post some examples of what you have tried... in any case if you exploded it, youd be better off doing it on `#`.  Such as your example above would need one check of the first letter of the whole string `['Dwarf ','jokes are only funny if you keep em ','short']`  But I would prefer a Regex, not sure what issue your having with them.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Code is easy, I am just looking for input as I want to improve performance. Also, your idea makes more sense as there would be nothing to iterate over in a large portion of cases.

Comment: If you expect multibyte input, you should use regular expressions

Comment: `I am just looking for input as I want to improve performance`- Well I just saved you about a billion iterations with the above ^ :-p